# How to toggle pagination of a jquery datatable on button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination, datatables, jquery-pagination

I have tried with the following ideas, but it all has few issues:

**Idea #1:**

```
var $oTable = $('#table').DataTable();
$oTable .settings()[0].oFeatures.bPaginate = !($oTable .settings()[0].oFeatures.bPaginate);
$oTable.draw('page');
```

Issue: It toggles the pagination but **page-numbers at the bottom remains as it is**. For example, if the datatable has pages with pagination, and we toggled the pagination it toggles fine but the div at the bottom of datatable that contains all the 5 page-numbers of the table, doesn't hide. I need to write extra code to hide the div that contains page-numbers.

**Idea #2:**

```
var $oTable = $('#table').DataTable();
if ($oTable.page.len() == -1) {
      $oTable.page.len(10).draw('page');} 
else {
      $oTable.page.len(-1).draw('page');}
```

Issue: It toggles the pagination but **page-numbers at the bottom of the table doesn't hide**. Considering the example of last scenario, in this scenario it becomes one page instead of 5 pages. But the problem is the div containing page-numbers remains visible. Again, I need to write extra code to hide the div that contains page-numbers.

Please help me out so that I can toggle the pagination of the datatable and at the same time the div containing page-numbers gets hide.

Answer (score 0):

The developer says that

> There is no option to enable and disable features in DataTables on-the-fly at this time

here: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/35146/on-the-fly-change-of-option so I guess that settles that.